# Matlab using editbox to match database

Tags: database, matlab

I'm facing problem when changing the user input using editbox when retrieve value from database. 
The following is the working code.

```
conn = database('SQL', '', '');
name = input('what is your name: ', 's'); 

sqlquery = ['select Staff.staffPW   from imageProcessing.dbo.Staff '...
       'where Staff.staffID = ' '''' name ''''];

curs = exec(conn,sqlquery);

curs = fetch(curs);
curs.Data

close(curs)
close(conn)
```

But now when I changed the input using editbox, problem occured

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

conn = database('SQL', '', '');
name = get(handles.edit1,'String');


sqlquery = ['select Staff.staffPW   from imageProcessing.dbo.Staff '...
       'where Staff.staffID = ' '''' name ''''];

curs = exec(conn,sqlquery);

curs = fetch(curs);
curs.Data

close(curs)
close(conn)
```

I can get the correct pw from the working code, but the input from editbox I'm getting nothing. Anyone can teach me how to make it work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure that `edit1` is the correct edit box? And you're saying that `name` is empty?

Comment: @Suever hi, yes I'm sure the edit1 is the correct edit box. No matter what I enter in the edit box the ans = 0. Unlike the working code I will get 'No Data' as ans when i enter wrong name.

Comment: When you say `ans = 0` you mean `name = 0`? Or do you mean `curs.Data` = 0

Comment: @Suever curs.Data = 0

Comment: Maybe put a break point right after where you define `sqlquery` to ensure that it looks like you expect

Comment: @Suever still can't... any other way? thanks

Comment: Why can't you put a breakpoint in there?

Comment: @Suever I put a breakpoint after sqlquery, still getting curs.Data = 0

Comment: The point of the breakpoint is to *look* at the value of `sqlquery` to make sure that it looks like how you expect.

Comment: @Suever hi, i checked the query has no problem, and i tried to put the value directly in the variable, name = 'Staff1'; , which it worked, but it just dont work when i get the value from editbox.

Comment: Try trimming any whitespace from your returned string: `name = strtrim(get(handles.edit1, 'String')))`

Comment: @Suever still the same.. but when i try set the editbox and get it, set(handles.edit1, 'String', 'Staff1');
name = strtrim(get(handles.edit1, 'String')); it worked. Any idea?

Comment: What is the actualy value of `name` that you get when you look at it in the debugger?

Comment: @Suever when i display(name) without using set is     'staff1'
 with set is just    staff1

Comment: Is it a cell array maybe? `iscell(name)`?

Comment: @Suever hi! thanks so much for pointing it out, i think the edit box returned user input as cell array, it worked now! How i put your comment as accepted answer though.

Comment: I've added a formal answer for you that describes what is happening and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate issue is that the [`String` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol-properties.html#property_string) in your case is a cell array containing a string rather than just a plain string.

MATLAB edit-style `uicontrol`s are capable of displaying multiple lines of text. To fill in multiple lines of text, in these cases, the string can be passed in as a cell array of strings where each element is on a different line of the edit box.

```
control = uicontrol('style', 'edit', ...
                    'Max', 2, ...           % A two-line edit box
                    'String', {'Row1', 'Row2'});
```

Because of this, even for a single-line edit box, the `String` property *could* be a cell array of strings *or* just a string. Therefore, when retrieving values from an edit box, be sure to check if it is a cell array ([`iscell`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/iscell.html)) or a string ([`ischar`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html)) before using it.

So adapting this to your code, we could do something like the following

```
name = get(handles.edit1, 'String');

% Check to ensure it is a cell array of one string
if iscell(name) && numel(name) == 1
    name = name{1};
end

% Disallow non-strings, cell arrays of multiple strings, or empty strings
if ~ischar(name) || isempty(name)
    error('A valid string must be supplied!');
end

sqlquery = ['select Staff.staffPW   from imageProcessing.dbo.Staff '...
            'where Staff.staffID = ' '''' name ''''];
```